# Cytoscape.js: Force middle-click to behave as left-click

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Is it possible to allow middle-click of the mouse to drag the nodes and edges similarly to what left-click normally does when `userPanning` is enabled? My app barely ever requires panning, so I would like the default behavior to be box selection, and only allow panning on middle-click.

I have tried to catch all middle-click events and instead trigger a left-click with many variations of the code below ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cms7qt8L/4/)):

```js
cy.userPanningEnabled(false); //no panning by default
cy.boxSelectionEnabled(true); //box selection instead

$('#cy').on('mousedown', function(e) {

  if (e.which == 2) {
    // Middle click.
    cy.userPanningEnabled(true);
    // ..some code here to replicate left-click event, such as conceptually:
    // e.which = 1; $('#cy').trigger(e); 
  } else {
    cy.userPanningEnabled(false);
  }

});
```

However, no matter how I try it, I cannot seem to replicate the left-click event triggered within the cytoscape.js instance.

Does anyone know if this is doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no guarantees of when gesture checks are performed.  That means you can't reliably disable panning during a gesture event sequence.

As for middle click in particular, consider device/OS support:

- Linux: minority of mice
- Mac: no
- Windows desktop: minority of mice
- Windows touch: no
- iOS: no
- Android: no

Even if you support only desktop devices, you still would support only a minority of users by relying on middle click.

A more inclusive approach would be to have a toggle for pan mode and select mode, with select mode default.

Though I don't advise on using middle click, you can write your own gesture using it if you really want.  Panning logic is pretty simple, especially with `cy.panBy()`.

Comment: Thank you, @maxkfranz - you have me convinced.